# Bluetooth no COM port connection? ESP32

Tags: bluetooth, esp32

I am experiencing issues sending serial data via bluetooth with my ESP32. When the device is plugged in, I am able to call bluetooth, and connect to PC and even obtain the serial data via the registered bluetooth COM port after connecting. Though, once I remove the USB power, and power the ESP32 with a battery, I am still able to connect to the PC, but the COM port disappears therefore leaving me unable to choose the port to send data over.

I've tried adding this device to COM port but when I try to add my ESP connected device, I am returned with "parameter is incorrect".

[image: Failed Bluetooth COM port]

.
.

Usually the COM port is listed here

[image: ESP32 Bluetooth COM port failure]

I know others have posted about this to other forums but none of seemed to solve the problem cut and dry. I also experienced this issue with HC-05 on Arduino Nano

Would appreciate any help I can get with this. I'm sure there is a simple solution that I just haven't come cross yet, as I'm relatively new to all this

Thx in advance

Comment: What battery are you using to power it?

Comment: Perhaps the COM-port you're trying to access is the one provided by the USB chip that might not be powered when you use a battery? If you can, get power from a USB power bank or a USB phone charger, and see if the COM port appears again.